# How to update Angular data model when static html element changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the [editable-table](https://mindmup.github.io/editable-table/) jQuery plugin to make a table editable. It's easy to use, lean and very effective.

The markup is this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="o in orders">
   <td ng-bind="o.name"></td>
   <td ng-bind="o.weight"></td>
   <td ng-bind="o.dimensions"></td>
</tr>
```

The table is made editable by calling:

```
$('#ordertable').editableTableWidget();
```

It works very well: the table shows up nicely, and it is editable. If the data model changes, the table is refreshed as well.

However, because I use `ng-bind`, the binding is one-way, and changes in the table is not automatically propagated to the data model. And `ng-model` doesn't work because it is not an input field.

Since I am new to Angular, I don't know the proper way to update my data model. I could do it using plain JS, but I would like to do it the Angular way.

**Which is the correct way to propagate changes back to the model?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you shouldn't mix angular way of updating values and editable plugin. Angular does not know about plugin and otherwise so they cannot work together like that.

Just try to do it without plugin:

`<tr ng-repeat="o in orders">
   <td><input type="text"  ng-model="o.name" /></td>
   <td><input type="text"  ng-model="o.weight" /></td>
   <td><input type="text"  ng-model="o.dimensions" /></td>
</tr>`

Comment: There are many great answers for my question and I am grateful for all of them as they all improved my understanding of Angular. But I choose this one for it's  simpleness. This is the solution I will use, at least for now.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you make any changes using jquery model will not be automatically updated because angular is not aware of changes you made and digest cycle is not triggered you can explicitly trigger digest cycle like this

```
  $scope.$digest();
 //but this will event not work
```

So to update your model you have to explicitly assign value to model as well, if you are using jquery

Answer (score 0):

There is one other way to solve this problem. Instead of using editable-table plugin of jquery use 'contenteditable' in table cells and use ng-model instead of ng-bind. And can write a directive for this contenteditable to update the model. There is an example for this in AngularJS site itself at the end of this page https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

I have copied the directive code from there and changed your html accordingly.

```js
directive('contenteditable', ['$sce', function($sce) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
    require: '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      if (!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model

      // Specify how UI should be updated
      ngModel.$render = function() {
        element.html($sce.getTrustedHtml(ngModel.$viewValue || ''));
      };

      // Listen for change events to enable binding
      element.on('blur keyup change', function() {
        scope.$evalAsync(read);
      });
      read(); // initialize

      // Write data to the model
      function read() {
        var html = element.html();
        // When we clear the content editable the browser leaves a <br> behind
        // If strip-br attribute is provided then we strip this out
        if ( attrs.stripBr && html == '<br>' ) {
          html = '';
        }
        ngModel.$setViewValue(html);
      }
    }
  };
}]);
```

```html
<tr ng-repeat="o in orders">
   <td contenteditable ng-model="o.name"></td>
   <td contenteditable ng-model="o.weight"></td>
   <td contenteditable ng-model="o.dimensions"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: If I use ng-model instead of ng-bind, there is no data in the table. What does $sce in the directive definition refer to?

Comment: add 'ngSanitize' module as well "angular.module('customControl', ['ngSanitize'])"

Comment: Please refer to the last example at the end of this page https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController, Its explained briefly there

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should not use jquery based plugins in an angular app. They don't mix well. Better look for similar angular based plugin.

What I did?
Took the input element which is used by the plugin to get user input (Editable cell) and compiled it with angular $compile service.

I hope this will work.

**HTML** :

```
 <div ng-app='app' ng-controller='mainCtrl' my-input>
     <table id="ir" >
       <tr ng-repeat="o in orders">
         <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in o"  ng-bind="value" ng-click="setCurrentCell($parent.$index, key)"></td>
       </tr>
     </table>
 </div>
```

**Controller** :

```
controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
   setTimeout(function(){
      $('#ir').editableTableWidget();
   });

   $scope.orders = [{name:1, weight : 10}, {name:2, weight : 20}];
   var editableOrder  = {};
   $scope.setCurrentCell = function(index, key){
        editableOrder.index = index;
       editableOrder.key = key;
   }
   $scope.myEdit = function(newVal){
    $scope.orders[editableOrder.index][editableOrder.key] = newVal;
   }
})
```

**Directive**

```
directive('myInput', ['$compile', function( $compile){
   return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            setTimeout(function(){
              var input = element.find('input');
              input.attr('ng-model', 'val');
              input.attr('ng-change', 'myEdit(val)');
              $compile(input)(scope);
           })
       }
   }
}]);
```